# Sex Robotics for everyone male and female

Tags: mobile-robot

How much would a sex robot cost, and is it ethically correct?

Comment: Probably quite a lot when you consider all technological advancements.

Comment: Sex robots would be cheaper than you think.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Ollie, but I'm afraid that questions like this are essentially opinion polls, which are [discouraged on stack exchange](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/). We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for a list of advantages and disadvantages for different options are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Answer (score 1):

Cost wise, the robots would only constantly decrease in price as the technology is currently infantile and very expensive but soon itll be relatively cheap and widely understood. Ethic wise, fleshlights are allowed so why wouldn't sex robots be right? ^^